# How to debug pyglet/opengl bus errors

Tags: opengl, debugging, pyglet

I'm using pyglet for game development, and sometimes encounter "bus errors". They are not consistently repeatable, and whenever I try to do simple debugging (eg move/remove variables, etc), the errors will eventually disappear entirely. I feel like I am encountering the notorious "heisenbug" class of errors.

Intuitively, I feel like the problem is likely due to pyglet/opengl/video card interaction, but of course this is only a hunch. So my question is: how do I debug this kind of problem?

Comment: I guess you need some kind of equivalent of the good old "core dump"+gdb.

Comment: Are you making any OpenGL calls yourself, or just via pyglet calls?

Comment: @Lohoris well, I did use gdb once, but didn't understand what to do with it; is that all I should be doing in this case?

Comment: @Kylotan all are pyglet calls

Comment: @EdwardTeach: you need to make pyglet produce core dumps, and need a debugger (like gdb) to analyze them. Or, you can directly run your game through a debugger, but this could cause the bug to disappear for weird reasons.

Comment: @Lohoris sounds like an answer :) If you'd like to elaborate a bit in an answer below, and/or point me to some URLs, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Would someone mind explaining what a "bus error" is? It refers to the graphics bus? How can a bus have programming-related errors?

Comment: @kaoD: as I said, unless I'm not mistaken, it's just a segmentation fault. Why it is called "bus error" instead of "segmentation fault" is beyond me, though probably that's because it's not the *exact* same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward thing to do is to run your game through a debugger. `pdb` is python's default debugger, but IIRC there are good alternatives, such as `bpython`. Once an error happens, you'll be in the python's console and be able to debug the problem.

Since a "bus error" is, unless I'm not mistaken, something similar to a good old "segmentation fault", I *guess* you could instead somehow have it drop a core dump and analyze that, which is a less invasive method than running through a debugger... but unless you find quick and easy instruction about how to do that, I wouldn't bother.